# Restarting Windows service at specific time

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have the following code in my Windows service application:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    StartProgram program = new StartProgram();
    Task.Run(() => program.Start(args));
}
```

How can I modify the code in a way that it will restart itself at midnight everyday?

Comment: Why itself ? You can call OnStop and OnStart.

Comment: Do you really want to mess with code when you can always do it with [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)? Even more you can write `.bat` file that create this kind of task on your service deploy.

Comment: Why you want to restart? If you want to run something at specific time then use Scheduled Task.

Comment: I understand that I can use Task Scheduler to do it. But I am told not use it, due to some enterprise constrains. Any help from the code point of view?

Comment: A service can't restart itself, that doesn't make sense.  But it doesn't look as if that's what your code is trying to do.  You need to clarify the question.